# Swift type conversions

Tags: swift, type-conversion

All:

According to the Swift Programming book, p. 52, the code below should not work because x is Int64 and y is obviously Int16, yet the Swift playground approves.

```
var x:Int = 32
var y:Int16 = 12

x + y
```

If I use -, * or /, the compiler does object, so is this a bug?  If not, what's different about +?

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator has two generic declarations that can handle a `Strideable` value on one side and a value on the other side that matches the first value's `Stride` alias. It works in this case because (a) `Int16` conforms to `Strideable` via `RandomAccessIndexType`, and `Int` is the `Stride` alias for `Int16` and all the other integer types.

In other words, you're calling the first of these functions, not the second:

```
// Int on the left, Int16 on the right:
func +<T : Strideable>(lhs: T.Stride, rhs: T) -> T

// Int16 would have to be on both sides:
func +(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
```

*Documentation:* [`Int16` type](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Int16/), [`+` operator](http://swifter.natecook.com/operator/pls/), [`Strideable` protocol](http://swifter.natecook.com/protocol/Strideable).