# Why this code crashes on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, 32-bit

The following code:

```
func getCurrentMillis() -> Int64 {
    return Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}
```

crashes on [32 bit] iPhone 5 with message:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

I don't understand why seems that result of this calculation should fit into `Int64`, or am I missing something?

Stacktrace shows this (`TextProcessor.textDidChange()` calls `getCurrentMillis()`):

[image]

**Per OOPer's request, I add the relevant code of TextProcessor:**

```
var timeOfLastInput: Int64 = 0

...

if getCurrentMillis() - timeOfLastInput > 150 {
    textMap.cursorPosition = nil
}
```

**Update:**
I've sent bug report to Apple.

Comment: If you know `Int64` is available on 32-bit devices, why don't you show the code of `TextProcessor.textDidChange()`. I can assure you your `getCurrentMillis()` works fine in 32-bit devices. The problem resides in the caller's side.

Comment: `Int64` *is* available on 32-bit systems. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure that the crash is in the getCurrentMillis function? I cannot see that from the stack backtrace.

Comment: @Martin R top of stacktrace doesn't mention it, but seems it crashes _because_ of it, i.e. when I change `Int64` to `TimeInterval` it works fine.

Comment: What's the type of `timeOfLastInput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on in the Swift compiler, but when you write:

```
if getCurrentMillis() - timeOfLastInput > 150 {
```

Swift uses this one in the many overloaded subtraction operators:

```
public func -<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T.Stride
```

(Tested with Xcode 8.2.1.)

Unfortunately, `Int64.Stride` is `Int`, so the result of the operation overflows when `timeOfLastInput` is `0` in 32-bit systems.

To workaround this behaviour of Swift, you can change the line to:

```
if getCurrentMillis() > timeOfLastInput + 150 {
```

---

Anyway, you'd better send a [bug report to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [to swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).

Comment: Good catch! A similar issue was observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496415/swift-type-conversions.

Comment: I assume that `if getCurrentMillis() - timeOfLastInput > Int64(150)` would work as well. – But anyway, this behavior is not intuitive and goes against the claimed "safety" of Swift.

Comment: I'm curious, where it's stated that `Int64.Stride` is `Int`?

Comment: @SerhiiYakovenko, check the definition of `Strideable`. Its associatedtype `Stride` is inferred from the definition of `distance(to:)` or `advanced(by:)`. In case of `Int64`, they are defined in the extension of `SignedInteger` as `public func distance(to other: Self) -> Int` and `public func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self`.

Answer (score -2):

As you already know your iphone 5 runs on an 32 bits system. You want to use an Int coded on 64 bits. Actually, it can't match. Your iphone can't store it.

To extends the_dahiya_boy's solution : Int size is the same as Int32 on a 32bits system and is the same size as Int64 on a 64bits sytem.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_461)